# Merge multiple mutually exclusive factor columns into a single column

Tags: r, merge, categorical-data

Say I have three columns in a data frame.  I want to merge these into a single column.  Each of the three columns is a binary attribute such as green/yellow, red/blue, black/white, etc.

I want to merge all of these into a single column with multiple

```
 row1=c(0,0,1)
 row2=c(1,0,0)
 row3=c(0,1,0)
 df=data.frame(rbind(row1,row2,row3))
```

Is there a way to merge each of these columns into a single column?  The single column would now have to have six different factors instead of the two it already has.

Can anyone show me how to code this?

Comment: Why six and not eight levels?

Comment: Do you intend the result to have nine rows?

Comment: Hi sorry i think my example was hard to follow.  If each column was red/blue, black/white, green/yellow each column has only two possible values.   Imagine this is a car...it can be only one color.  So I would transform this into 1 column: "Color" so it would have 6 possible values listed above.   However, since the data I am working with is coded 0/1 for each column I would need a way to make this clear.

Comment: Your example doesn't reflect that.  For example, say that the first column in each each row represents red/blue, the second black/white and the third green/yellow, represented by the values 0/1 in the columns.  Then the first row says red, black, and yellow.

Comment: If these are factors then PLEASE edit the question to reflect this. (As it stands your comment-correction is incoherent.)

Comment: @ user3788557 : your feedback to answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can encode these as you would encode a binary number, by assigning increasing powers of two for each column.  You want to multiply each row by `c(1,2,4)` and then take the sum.

```
# The multiplier, powers of two
x <- 2^(seq(ncol(df))-1)
x
## [1] 1 2 4

# The values
apply(df, 1, function(row) sum(row*x))
## row1 row2 row3 
## 4    1    2
```

To add this as a new column:

```
df$new <- apply(df, 1, function(row) sum(row*x))
df
##      X1 X2 X3 new
## row1  0  0  1   4
## row2  1  0  0   1
## row3  0  1  0   2
```

Comment: I thought they were looking for something like: `data.frame(new=factor(c((1:2)[row1 + 1],(3:4)[row2 + 1],(5:6)[row3 + 1])))` ?

Comment: @thelatemail Interesting interpretation, but as it does result in six levels as was requested, perhaps it is correct.  Makes more sense if there are labels to the original factors.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
> df
     X1 X2 X3
row1  0  0  1
row2  1  0  0
row3  0  1  0
> 
> 
> mm = melt(df)
No id variables; using all as measure variables
> 
> mm$new = paste(mm$variable,mm$value,sep='_')
> 
> mm
  variable value  new
1       X1     0 X1_0
2       X1     1 X1_1
3       X1     0 X1_0
4       X2     0 X2_0
5       X2     0 X2_0
6       X2     1 X2_1
7       X3     1 X3_1
8       X3     0 X3_0
9       X3     0 X3_0
```

mm$new is the column you want.

Comment: Or `paste(colnames(df)[col(df)],as.matrix(df),sep="_")`

Comment: Very elegant one liner.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
> df$X1 = ifelse(df$X1==0,'green','yellow')
> df$X2 = ifelse(df$X2==0,'red','blue')
> df$X3 = ifelse(df$X3==0,'black','white')
> 
> df
         X1   X2    X3
row1  green  red white
row2 yellow  red black
row3  green blue black
> 
> unlist(df)
     X11      X12      X13      X21      X22      X23      X31      X32      X33 
 "green" "yellow"  "green"    "red"    "red"   "blue"  "white"  "black"  "black"
```